# How to populate temp table structure fast from source table in sp?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a temp table structure from a physical table in sp.

I have two approaches

```
Select * into #temptable from MainTable where NULL=NULL
```

or

```
Select * into #temptable from MainTable where 1=0
```

I have many statement in sp that creates temp table structures, so it is necessary to opt a better approach for temp table creation.

Please let me know the better way to create a temp table with high performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, you may use `TOP(0)`:

```
SELECT  TOP(0) *
INTO    #TempTable
FROM    SourceTable
```

But in all these three cases (`SELECT TOP(0)`, `WHERE NULL=NULL`, `WHERE 1=0`), the execution plan will be the same:
[image]

In all these cases, SQL Server will know from query optimization phase that these queries do not generate rows at execution time. So instead of reading data from source table (`Sales.SalesOrderHeader` in this case) the server will use a [`Constant Scan` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178579%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

1)

> [...] the Query Optimizer may know that no records can satisfy a predicate
>   even before touching any page of data
>   [(Source)](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/tag/contradiction-detection/)

2)

> Contradiction Detection is an optimization that recognizes when a
>   query is written in such a way that it will never return any rows at
>   all.
>   [(Source)](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/13-things-you-should-know-about-statistics-and-the-query-optimizer/)

**Conclusion**: you could use any of these solution.

**Note**: You may use `WHERE NULL=NULL` only if `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`. If `ANSI_NULLS` setting is `OFF` then `WHERE NULL=NULL` filter will be always `true` and the execution plan will be:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Select * into #temptable from MainTable where 1=0` is the right method. Although `Select * into #temptable from MainTable where NULL=NULL` gives the same result, the best practice is NULL comparison must happen with `IS` operator. Also `1=0` comparison is common across the developers.

Comment: If I will check NULL IS NULL then temp table will be created having all the records same as source table.